# Performance of null coalescing operator when checking if List<T> is null

Tags: c#

I have a `List<int>` which gets its values from a method

```
List<int> items = GetIntegerStuff();
```

so the current code to avoid NullReference exception looks like this

```
if (items == null)
{
    items = new List<int>();
}
```

I've changed it to this because I like short code - but my Senior developer says this is bad because if there are items (which happens about 90% of all requests), the whole list will be assigned and it's bad for performance. Is this true?

```
items = items ?? new List<int>();
```

Comment: While your assignment would work, you could simplify it to `List<int> items = GetIntegerStuff() ?? new List<int>();`

Comment: If you think about it in the literal sense, you are doing extra work your way.  You can only assign items if items is null, or you can assign items _every single time_.  How much extra work is another story.  It might only be a little bit, but is it really worth it just to use an operator that does not really solve the problem you need to solve.  Just use an if statement and listen to your senior devs

Comment: Assigning a reference to a local has negligible cost. It does not duplicate the list.

Comment: Can you change GetIntegerStuff() so that it returns an empty list instead of null?

Comment: The really *bad* thing is `GetIntegerStuff` implementation: we should almost always return an empty collection, not `null`

Comment: @derpirscher / jonaglon  / Dmitry Bychenko  I know these workarounnds, this is about technical bahaviour of .NET

Comment: Did your "senior developer" hear about premature optimization? Assigning a variable to a reference is certainly not a performance killer in any way. The performance cost is theoretical and negligible if any.

Comment: @Toshi .NET is a library.  You're asking about the C# language.  And if you want to know what the performance costs of *the code you've already written* are, then *run the code and see for yourself* what the difference is between the two solutions you've already written.

Comment: @mm8 its not a "performance killer" but it _is_ extra work.  In my opinion the `if x == null` more clear does the extra work only when necessary.  I wouldnt reject a pull request because of it though <EricLippertPerformanceRantLink>

Comment: It must be a misunderstanding: `items.ToList()` - list *cloning* - i.e. *copying each item* can well bad for performance (imagine a list with 1 billion items). 
On the contrary `items = some_other_list` is coping a *reference* (`8` bytes) which is fast and doesn't depend of `list` size at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the way you are using it, the two are exactly the same in terms of performance, because they compile to exactly the same thing.

Test code:

```
static void NullCoalescing(List<int> a)
{
    a = a ?? new List<int>();
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
static void IfStatement(List<int> a)
{
    if(a == null) a = new List<int>();
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Compiles to:

```
C.NullCoalescing(System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Int32>)
    L0000: push rsi
    L0001: sub rsp, 0x20
    L0005: test rcx, rcx
    L0008: jnz L0044
    L000a: mov rcx, 0x7ffb92892a78
    L0014: call 0x7ffb94712540
    L0019: mov rsi, rax
    L001c: mov ecx, 0x1
    L0021: mov edx, 0x43
    L0026: call 0x7ffb9487ff10
    L002b: mov rdx, 0x2966e0ddef8
    L0035: mov rdx, [rdx]
    L0038: lea rcx, [rsi+0x8]
    L003c: call 0x7ffb94713e70
    L0041: mov rcx, rsi
    L0044: call System.Console.WriteLine(System.Object)
    L0049: nop
    L004a: add rsp, 0x20
    L004e: pop rsi
    L004f: ret

C.IfStatement(System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Int32>)
    L0000: push rsi
    L0001: sub rsp, 0x20
    L0005: test rcx, rcx
    L0008: jnz L0044
    L000a: mov rcx, 0x7ffb92892a78
    L0014: call 0x7ffb94712540
    L0019: mov rsi, rax
    L001c: mov ecx, 0x1
    L0021: mov edx, 0x43
    L0026: call 0x7ffb9487ff10
    L002b: mov rdx, 0x2966e0ddef8
    L0035: mov rdx, [rdx]
    L0038: lea rcx, [rsi+0x8]
    L003c: call 0x7ffb94713e70
    L0041: mov rcx, rsi
    L0044: call System.Console.WriteLine(System.Object)
    L0049: nop
    L004a: add rsp, 0x20
    L004e: pop rsi
    L004f: ret
```

As you can see, they compile to be exactly the same.

View here:

https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALANALiAhgZwLYB8ACAGABJgRgG4BYAKB3wKlIoGZ8AmXAYVwG9zzceqJ8ouAHIBXADZiWAe0RiApsgDGASwB2AcwAUAGWXI4AHjVwAfLkQBKbr05le987gC8jgPyvcquQHdcu/UaqppoWtA68hACcmpZhvAC+1jyE/JiCAJIAZgDKcIhwcqhyQTp6hsZmlkkc1fbKmTHOLqriYhaOzT5+ZYHBobURBNGx1Ylk8UA

Answer (score 1):

These are the possible approaches:

```
//APPROACH 1
List<int> items = GetIntegerStuff();
if (items == null)
{
    items = new List<int>();
}

//APPROACH 2
List<int> items = GetIntegerStuff() ?? new List<int>();

//APPROACH 3
List<int> items = GetIntegerStuff();
items = items ?? new List<int>();

//APPROACH 4
List<int> items = GetIntegerStuff();
items = items == null ? new List<int>() : items;
```

I would go for the number 2, it is the cleanest from my point of view.

---

Just for completeness, there are scenarios where you can find something like that:

```
class Program
{
    private static List<int> _items = new List<int>();

    private static List<int> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }

        set
        {
            _items = value ?? new List<int>();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //APPROACH 5
        Items = GetIntegerStuff();
    }

    private static Random Random = new Random();
    private static List<int> GetIntegerStuff()
    {
        switch (Random.Next(0, 2))
        {
            case 0:
                return null;
                break;
            default:
                return new List<int>();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Is this bad for performance?**

```
List<int> items = GetIntegerStuff();
items = items ?? new List<int>();
```

No, but it will actually execute more instructions respect to:

```
List<int> items = GetIntegerStuff();
if (items == null)
{
    items = new List<int>();
}
```

or

```
List<int> items = GetIntegerStuff() ?? new List<int>();
```

Comment: While this shows various methods to do the same task, it does not address the original performance question.